# ProGuard: keep implementations for interface annotated with @Keep

Tags: java, interface, annotations, proguard

I would like to annotate some interfaces in my application with a custom `@Keep` annotation and configure ProGuard so as to

- not obfuscate the annotated interface and its methods,
- not obfuscate implementations for those interface methods in implementing classes.

I tried something like

```
# Kept interfaces and all their methods
-keep interface @com.foo.bar.annotation.Keep * {
    <methods>;
}

# Classes implementing kept interfaces
-keep class * implements @com.foo.bar.annotation.Keep *
```

but obviously the syntax is invalid. I tried other things, but the ProGuard documentation and its examples are not really clear about the exact syntax and what is possible under which circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I just happened to bump into the solution when playing around. Actually it is much simpler than I thought:

```
# Annotated interfaces (including methods which are also kept in implementing classes)
-keep @com.foo.bar.annotation.Keep interface * {
    *;
}
```

<s>Obviously it was wrong to specify `<methods>` on an interface keep clause, maybe because ProGuard only filters for actual method implementations, not mere method declarations as can be found in interface declarations.</s>

The above syntax seems to keep the full interface (class name, method names) plus all implementing method names, which is logical if I think about it, because if I do implement an interface I cannot change (obfuscate) the method names anyway.

Comment: You can find a series of examples in examples/annotations/lib/annotations.pro in the ProGuard distribution. The specifications are intended to look like Java, but with wildcards. Note that the wildcard <methods> works fine for interfaces as well.

Comment: Thanks Eric, someone else also said that before, but deleted his answer because it did not directly solve the problem. I have looked at that resouce already and even though it does not really answer the question it gave me lots of ideas. I also noticed that probably my syntax error `interface @Keep` instead of `@Keep interface` was the real problem, not the usage of `<method>`.

Answer (score 0):

This helped a similar situation I had:

[Proguard stops Javascript in WebView from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815932/proguard-stops-javascript-in-webview-from-working)

I imagine the principle would be the same...

Comment: Thanks, but the answer does not apply to my question. My problem are not annotated methods but annotated interfaces.