# Android Camera issues using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to use proguard on my android app and it some how creates issues with the camera.
The app basically is used to take a photo of a document.  However, when the app is proguard, the app no longer use the camera feature.

I've tried to create a proguard config that excludes most of the class, but I don't think its working.  Any idea of how to just exclude all the files possible so then I can work backwards to figure what went wrong?

The application references a jar file that references another library that has all the code.

Let's say its application references "container.jar."  Container.jar is built as a wrapper for the library sdk let's say "sdk.jar"

Any advice on how to debug this problem?
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't with the camera.  It dealt with the fact that the application was using a javascript bridge to bridge with a web app.  proguard stripped out the code need to trigger the camera action.

Solution found here:
[Proguard stops Javascript in WebView from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815932/proguard-stops-javascript-in-webview-from-working)