# Android WebView Javascript calls not working with Proguard

Tags: android, webview, proguard, obfuscation

I've been facing a problem that seem very common in Android.
My Webview with a custom Javascript interface is not working when the application is in release mode.
I am unable to call JS code from Java.

I feel that the problem is linked to proguard, as the Webview works normally in release mode as soon as I set the "minifyEnabled" to "false".

My proguard mappings are looking like this, I'm not sure if this is alright:

```
com.company.app.jsBridge.BaseJavascriptInterface -> 
com.company.app.jsBridge.BaseJavascriptInterface:
    java.util.Map mCallbacks -> a
    java.util.Map mHandlers -> b
    com.company.app.jsBridge.BridgeWebView mWebView -> c
    29:29:void send(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String):0:0 -> send
    ...
```

I have already browsed through Stackoverflow related questions such as these, and a few others:

[Proguard stops Javascript in WebView from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815932/proguard-stops-javascript-in-webview-from-working)
[How to configure proguard for javascript interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629507/how-to-configure-proguard-for-javascript-interface)
[Proguard mess Javascript Interface functions when targeting SDK in Android Manifest above 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260126/proguard-mess-javascript-interface-functions-when-targeting-sdk-in-android-manif)

I tried applying the answers of these questions and my proguard file now looks like this:

```
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers class * {
   @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class com.company.app.jsBridge.BaseJavascriptInterface {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.company.app.jsBridge.BaseJavascriptInterface
```

And my interface:

```
package com.company.app.jsBridge;


public abstract class BaseJavascriptInterface {

    // Callbacks to execute after successful JS calls
    private final Map<String, IOnBridgeCallback> mCallbacks;

    // Handler methods that will be available to the JS
    private final Map<String, IBridgeHandler> mHandlers;

    private BridgeWebView mWebView;

    public BaseJavascriptInterface(Map<String, IOnBridgeCallback> callbacks, Map<String, IBridgeHandler> handlers, BridgeWebView webView) {
        mCallbacks = callbacks;
        mHandlers = handlers;
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String send(String handlerName, String data) {
        //
    }
}
```

Other things that I have tried:

- Running on both an emulator and a physical device, as I read that emulators could have a different behaviour with proguard
- Using the @Keep annotation on the Javascript interface

Does anybody know what is wrong with my config or if I'm not looking at the right place ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution by myself with the help of this post : [Proguard issue while using GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563916/proguard-issue-while-using-gson)

I needed to preserve both the Javascript Interface in Proguard like I did before, as well as the classes that I used for JSON communication between Java and JS. Gson was unable to properly serialize the data because the models were not preserved.